# NullPointerException when attempting to serialize Avro GenericRecord containing array

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro

I am trying to publish Avro (into Kafka) and get a `NullPointerException` when attempting to write the Avro object with the `BinaryEncoder`.

Here is the abbreviated stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null of array of com.mycode.DeeplyNestedObject of array of com.mycode.NestedObject of union of com.mycode.ParentObject
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.npe(GenericDatumWriter.java:132) ~[avro-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:126) ~[avro-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:73) ~[avro-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:60) ~[avro-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at com.mycode.KafkaAvroPublisher.send(KafkaAvroPublisher.java:61) ~[classes/:na]
    ....
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:73) ~[avro-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:112) ~[avro-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter.writeField(SpecificDatumWriter.java:87) ~[avro-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:143) ~[avro-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:105) ~[avro-1.8.1.jar:1.8.1]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
```

Here is the send method in my code where the exception occurs:

```
private static final EncoderFactory ENCODER_FACTORY = EncoderFactory.get();
private static final SpecificDatumWriter<ParentObject> PARENT_OBJECT_WRITER = new SpecificDatumWriter<>(ParentObject.SCHEMA$);
public void send(ParentObject parentObject) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        binaryEncoder = ENCODER_FACTORY.binaryEncoder(stream, binaryEncoder);
        PARENT_OBJECT_WRITER.write(parentObject, binaryEncoder);  // Exception HERE
        binaryEncoder.flush();
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, stream.toByteArray()));
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        logger.debug("Problem publishing message to Kafka.", ioe);
    }
}
```

In the schema, the `NestedObject` contains an array of `DeeplyNestedObject`. I've done enough debugging to see that the `NestedObject` does, in fact, contain an array of `DeeplyNestedObject` or an empty array if none are present. Here is the relevant part of the schema:

```
[ { "namespace": "com.mycode.avro"
  , "type": "record"
  , "name": "NestedObject"
  , "fields":
    [ { "name": "timestamp", "type": "long", "doc": "Instant in time (milliseconds since epoch)." }
    , { "name": "objs", "type": { "type": "array", "items": "DeeplyNestedObject" }, "doc": "Elided." }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stacktrace coming out of Avro is misleading. The problem is likely one level deeper than the class the `Exception` message indicates.

When it says "`null of array of com.mycode.DeeplyNestedObject of array of com.mycode.NestedObject of union of com.mycode.ParentObject`", it means that one of the fields inside the `DeeplyNestedObject` is expected to be an `array` but is found to be `null`. (It completely makes sense to misinterpret that as meaning that the `DeeplyNestedObject` is `null` inside of `NestedObject`.)

You'll need to inspect the fields of `DeeplyNestedObject` and figure out which `array` is not being serialized correctly. The problem is likely to be located where the `DeeplyNestedObject` is created. It will have a field with type `array` which isn't being populated in all cases by the serializer before calling the send method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about objects you have, but what I see in your example is that you have incorrect avro-schema.

DeeplyNestedObject in avro is a Record, so your schema must be like this:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "NestedObject",
  "namespace": "com.mycode.avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "timestamp",
      "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "objs",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "DeeplyNestedObject",
        "fields": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Of course all fields of DeeplyNestedObject you need to declare in "fields": [] related to the DeeplyNestedObject record.